# Why can't go back page after twice back to index?

Tags: javascript, cordova, routes, html-framework-7

I'm using Cordova + Framework 7

- I have 3 page : `index`, `page1`, `page2`
- When i back to index like this page2 -> page1 -> index, i can't press `go page1` button in index.html. I must reload index page, the `go page1` button so working.

**routes.js**

```
{
    path: '/page1/',
    async: function (routeTo, routeFrom, resolve, reject) {
        axios.get('').then(response => {
            var data = response.data;
            resolve({
                componentUrl: './pages/page1.html'
            }, {
                context: {
                    data: data,
                }
            });
        })
    }
}, {
    path: '/page2/:id',
    async: function (routeTo, routeFrom, resolve, reject) {
        axios.get('' + id).then(function (response) {
            var data = response.data;
            resolve({
                componentUrl: './pages/page2.html'
            }, {
                context: {
                    data: data
                }
            });
        })

    }
}
```

**Back button in page1, page2**

```
<a href="#" class="back link" data-force="true">
    <img src="img/icon-back.png" alt="">
</a>
```

**Button go to page1 in index.html**

.html

```
<a href="#" class="button button-raised button-fill" id="go-page1">go page1</a>
```

.js

```
$$('#go-page1').on('click', function () {
    app.views.main.router.navigate('/page1/');

}
```

**Button go to page2 in page1**

```
{{#each data}}
<div class="col">
    <div class="card demo-card-header-pic">
        <a href="/page2/{{id}}">{{name}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: is it the same behaviour if you pass path in index.html href ? ( `<a href="/page1/" class="......">go pages1</a> ` )

Comment: @Djiggy No. If i pass index -> page1 -> back to index it's ok.
 Error just happend when i pass path index -> page1 -> page2

Answer (score 1):

you can fix that by one from these solution:

1)

```
$$('#go-page1').on('click', function () {
    app.views.main.router.navigate('/page1/', {reloadCurrent: true});

}
```

2) or in html link

```
<a class="back" data-ignore-cache="true" data-force="true">back</a>
```

3) ignore cache/history or refresh prev page by reloadPrevious like this:

```
mainView.router.back({url: 'index.html', force: true, ignoreCache: true,reload: true});
```